# Restrict APK to specific user

Tags: android

Due to some legal restrictions, Android Market for paid apps is not available in all countries.

Since there are requests here and then, I was thinking of an alternative way to let the user pay via the app, say simply via PayPal (not to the Android Market). And then ship a license-free (license-bypassing) recompiled .apk to him, with his user id (email) hard-coded in the .apk; such that only this user can use the app.

Is such a mechanism possible? If yes, how to achieve this? Any potential risks that the apk can be somehow misused?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds doable to me, but I probably wouldn't recommend it. If you send the APK then the user has then ability to take it and redistribute it as they please. What are you doing to ensure only that user can use the app? Hardcoding their email and some kind of authentication steps? Assuming that works, you *should* be safe as there is no worthwhile way to decompile an APK.

If it's just a couple of people I think it'll work. Any more than that and your distribution efforts are going to take as long as it took you to code it.